# How can I get the name of a symbolic link?

Tags: sed, symlink, cut

Output of a command looks something like this

```
# ls -l abc.zip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sri dba 122 Mar 27 23:37 /a/b/c/abc.zip -> /x/y/z/abc.zip
```

I need to extract/cut the whole path which comes after `->`. I have used `cut -f -d` but its not working some times, I guess column number is changing. So I need `sed` equivalent of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'cut' you can only specify single character delimiters.

For string delimiters an easy and clear option is awk. In your case  try:

```
ls -ls abc.zip | awk -F '->' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You should use readlink for this

Answer (score 5):

What you are reading is the information about a symlink. [Parsing `ls` is definitely a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

What about using [readlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) instead? It does *read value of a symbolic link*:

```
readlink abc.zip
```

Or with `-f` for the full path:

```
readlink -f abc.zip
```

---

See an example:

```
$ touch a         
$ ln -s a b          # we create a symbolic link "b" to the file "a"
$ ls -l b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 1 Apr  6 09:54 b -> a
$ readlink -f "b"    # we check the full "destination" of the symlink "b"
/home/me/a
$ readlink "b"       # we check the "destination" of the symlink "b"
a
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/^l.*->\s*//p' file
```